# Setting a sampling rate for capturing sensor data?

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors

I have been trying to find the correct answer to this but none of the solutions work. I am trying to get sensor data, specifically accelerometer data, from the phone after 5 seconds. I have written the following listener:

```
manager.registerListener(MainActivity.this, 
manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), 5000000, 5000000);
```

It is still gathering data really fast. I am writing out the accelerometer data to a CSV and it is massive. Is there a way to limit the number of times the the sensor detects a change?

Comment: Querying acceleration all 5 seconds only will yield very low meaning for a single reading (most of the times you will see just gravity). If you want to use it to detect motion, there is the significant motion sensor. If you want it for orientation better use the orientation sensor. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the predefined parameters while registering the listener:
 for example:
`SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST`
or
`SENSOR_DELAY_UI` which is the fastes possible time sampling rate. There are also parameters for a (much) lower frequency of the data samples. see the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager) for more.